# Storing dimensions in xml file in Android

Tags: android, css, xml, layout

I am trying to consistently use the same dimension in all the views in my android app (e.g., a left margin of 20dp). If I were using HTML, I would simply use a CSS file, but I am at a loss of how to do this on Android.

Is there a way I can store this value in a xml file inside res/values and then use it in layouts?

e.g., I thought of storing them in strings.xml like

```
<string name="app_wide_left_padding">20dp</string>
```

and then using the following text in layout.xml

```
android:paddingLeft="@string/app_wide_left_padding"
```

but I am not sure it will work. Am I on the right track?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Create a file called res/values/dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="icon_width">55dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="icon_height">55dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="photo_width">170dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="photo_height">155dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then reference them in your other xml:

```
android:padding="@dimen/icon_width">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use styles (res/values). [This article](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-themes-and-styles-in-android.html) will be a good start.

Comment: The name of the xml file does not matter, though making a structure within the xml files that you can easily understand is recommended...