# Android: Limit title width in landscape - Possible?

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to restrict the title in my app in landscape to e.g. 50% of the area on the left side. Is it possible to have something like:

[image: Title only on the right (resp. left) side]

For the portrait modus the current situation is fine.

Currently the title is already a custom title, but would be great to give the user more space :)

Comment: create dimen.xml and set values for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/11686495/1012284

Comment: Thx for the hint, but I still don't know how to restrict the title width to the right/left side. I don't get a real clue how this might help to restrict the width, cause it's only about the height...

Comment: do u know aboutEMS? try giving android:maxEms="10". you can give any integer values.

Comment: No, I didn't know about the ems, but didn't change anything. I put them into the Style, but not recognized there. In the title.xml there was also no change for the components. But I guess its due to the fill of the title which covers the whole area...

Comment: Without showing your code I cant do any thing @LeO.

Comment: True ;) How to post the code properly? [main-landscape](https://code.google.com/p/cuckoochess/source/browse/trunk/DroidFish/res/layout-land/main.xml) with the corresponding title.xml [title-land and portrait](https://code.google.com/p/cuckoochess/source/browse/trunk/DroidFish/res/layout/title.xml) I tried some changes, but I didn't succeed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the previous answer I found the solution with

```
_______________________________
|              |--------------|
|              || Title-View ||
|              |--------------|
|    View A    |    View B    |
|              |              |
|              |              |
|              |              |
-------------------------------
```

and a general Style which disables the app-title-header. Some side-effects are:

- since the title-view-components are not persistent I need to reinitialize them as soon as the device is rotated (prior this was not necessary) [But this is a minor effort]
- in the title-view I set `android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"` which layouts the view the same style as a regular Android-title
- I included hardcoded in the all layouts the Title-view with

  ```
      <include
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      layout="@layout/title_2_lines" />
  ```

  which is also no big deal and works great.

Thx for support cause the two different ideas helped a lot to figure out a way how to make it properly :)

Answer (score 1):

That title is part of the `View` (or `Fragment`?) on the right side of the screen. To do the same, simply put your title in a `View` that resides on the left half of the screen. You can use your already-existing layout for portrait orientation.

EDIT: *Based on the image provided*, I think that the layout of that application looks something like this:

```
_______________________________
|              |--------------|
|              ||   Title    ||
|              |--------------|
|    View A    |    View B    |
|              |              |
|              |              |
|              |              |
-------------------------------
```

and in terms of hierarchical layout, something like this:

```
Layout
  View A
    Stuff
  View B
    Title
    More Stuff
```

Comment: The title is part of a View. But I don't understand it practically. To put the title in a View means, I have to disable it in the landscape-view. I guess via code and not via xml. But then how to add it on the right side? I thought the title spans over the complete main-screen. Sorry, but I am not THAT firm with the layout-ing.

Comment: @LeO: See my diagram. If this isn't what you want, that's fine. It's what I see in the picture in your question.

Comment: Generally speaking the idea looks fine. The screenshot is a fake one, that's the goal I wanna achieve. Currently it spans over the whole area cause it's the same from portrait. But thanks for the moment for the idea, I guesses now I need to fumble around ;-)

Comment: Sorry, but seems like I am still stuck. Although I like your idea, the question remains how to do it practically? I have my title.xml which defines the title and the components. I make a `setContentView(R.layout.main)` and then `getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,title.xml)`. But to make it like you suggest, does it mean, to hide the application Title Bar? And how to specify for ViewB that it should use title.xml? Resp. set it?

Comment: Thx for support, especially for the drawing which gave me good overview in which direction to progress

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set the Android Title bar to be hidden and add your own TextView as shorter TitleBar.
This way you have more possibilites desgining your layout.

Comment: If I follow your advice, I am curious if I can reuse the specification of title.xml (==> How?) OR do I need to specify it once more? I mean the advantage to have it in the title.xml would be to have it in portrait and landscape with the same code and I don't have to worry about redefinition.

Comment: And one more question that just came into my mind is about the background-color. Cause currently Android is responsible, IFF I redesign it, than I have to take care - also for future changes. Is there currently an easy way to retieve them from the defaults?

Comment: You can always inflate an xml. Just look for the InflaterService on the Android Homepage. Also you can use the Background-Color from the current Android-System by using "android.R."

Comment: see my posted answer. Thx your hints helped me a lot.