# Styling ActionBar Spinner Navigation to look like it's title and subtitle

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use Spinner navigation in my actionbar. Everything works fine except styling.

I would like the spinner nav to look like an actionbar which has a title and a subtitle:
[image]

But if I use spinner nav, I have to set the title and subtitle to empty string and provide my own spinner view. Which I do, but it looks like this:
[image]

**QUESTION: What are the styles to make the spinner look the same as on the image above?**

Note: I tried setting TextViews textAppearance to `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"` and `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"` respectively, but it didn't work.

I use native Actionbar, not ABS.

Comment: In my opinion you should create your custom xml for spinner's item and play with text size to make it like that.

Comment: I would play with joy, but I'm pretty sure there are tons of different styles for different layouts. I know there are several different sizes for actionbar height and I can get them all with single `@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height` (this is for actionbarsherlock actually, but there is similar value for regulas Actionbar). I'm looking for something similar here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hieght of these items are defined in `/<android-sdk>/platforms/android-15/data/res/values/dimens.xml` file, like this:

```
<dimen name="action_bar_default_height">48dip</dimen>
<dimen name="action_bar_title_text_size">18dp</dimen>
<dimen name="action_bar_subtitle_text_size">14dp</dimen>
<dimen name="action_bar_subtitle_top_margin">-3dp</dimen>
<dimen name="action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin">5dip</dimen>
```

(Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11686495/989029)

You should redefine required values (Note that these values are different for various orientations, so you need several files as well) in your res folder and use them like this:

actionbar_spinner_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_title_text_size"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_subtitle_top_margin"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_subtitle_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I use this layout in a custom ArrayAdapter in getView() method. From your screenshots I assume you know the details.

All this gives the following result, that looks as expected on all devices I've tested.
[image]

Comment: I'll be trying this solution in few days (and accepting it then), but it looks great. Thanks!

Comment: actually I think it can be done even easier by referencing those values directly like `android:textSize="@anroid:dimen/action_bar_title_text_size"` but I have to check it. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing me to those values

Comment: Dunno, eclipse never showed me these values in autocomplete until I reimported them in my own file.

Comment: As I am continuing to work on my project, I've tweaked the answer a bit further.

Comment: How to change action_bar_title by clicking on the navigation drawer list item.