# Split Android attrs.xml resource file to get UI colors separated from the rest

Tags: android, android-resources

Is it possible to use another file other than attrs.xml to store a specific set of attributes like colors?

Now:

```
attrs.xml
```

I want to split into:

```
attrs.xml
colors.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can, just define a `colors.xml` in your `values` folder and place there your desired colors like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="my_blue">#c00e</color>
<color name="my_welcome_color">#3399cc</color>
<color name="my_transperent_white">#afff</color>
....
</resources>
```

Comment: So are you saying that all xml files will be intepreted for the contant and not for the file name?

Comment: color.xml is a special file that is recognized by android at compile time, and the colors you will define there will be defined automaticly in you self generated R file under the "public static final class color" part, so you will have access to them.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but all files inside the res-folder are evaluated. And all xml-files will be parsed. So everything inside the res-folder is added to your generated R.java.

Comment: yes you right, but for my understanding if you define you color in the attrs file then they will be placed under the "public static final class attr" section, while placing them in the colors file will place them under the "public static final class color" (I need to check this out, actually I never used the attrs file to define colors, but this is my guess). for you as a developer this does not makes any difference.

Comment: Can I do it also for dimen?

Comment: yes, you can, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885164/storing-dimensions-in-xml-file-in-android